# Jquery - Window.open using button but not returning back to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the current code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var win = window.open("URL...", "thePopUp", "");

var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
if (win==null || win.closed !==false || navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
    pause();
    alert("Oh No!  Something has gone wrong, please check the requirements before continuing.");
}
}, 10);
</script>
```

That basically opens in another window a page that users need to leave open to earn points on the site.  The popup window that is shown changes the URL every 20 seconds.

However it automatically opens when they open the page, I would like to use a button to start that above code off.  But when I tried this the popup window doesn't change the URL unless they press the button again.

So what I'm after is a way to open this popup window with a button but to not have to then use the button again and again afterwards so it doesn't go through the button any more.

Comment: can you show us the code when you tried to use the button?

Comment: I don't have that code any more, it's was just a simple button

Comment: What you have should work fine if you wrap it in a click event callback